# Troubleshooting ingress on kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I deployed ingress controller to my kubernetes cluster. However when i'm trying to access the pod i get HTTP 503. So i've tried to find the problem by accessing ingress controller's logs:

```
kubectl logs controllername-nginx-ingress-controller-6f486779b5-dnm8k -n kube-system
```

the piece of the log file that i'm interested in, looks like this:

```
10.244.0.1 - [10.244.0.1] - - [10/Dec/2018:16:54:12 +0000] "GET /identity HTTP/2.0" 503 599 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36" 271 0.000 [] - - - - d7f7ffd22d584e4a5da2b0fa2fae5665
```

as you can see i see absolutely nothing interesting there. I'm wondering if it's the entire log message as i see a bunch of dashes and a guid value at the end.

Next i decided to enrich ingress' logfiles:

```
kubectl edit deploy -n kube-system controllername-nginx-ingress-controller
```

deployment document shows up and i want to add extra line to args section:

```
  spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --v=5     < ------------ this line
        - other arguments here
```

once i close the deployment document i see this message:

```
error: deployments "misty-marmot-nginx-ingress-controller" is invalid
```

so what i'm doing wrong? is the log message really complete, in the current form it doesn't describe the error one bit. also why i can't change the logging level?

Comment: Have you tried to get verbose output in command as well: `kubectl logs <Pod-name> -v 5`? Can you share your `Ingress` resource configuration?

Comment: apparently it was a formatting issue when editing a deployment file using windows notepad. to solve it i copy-pasted already existing argument and just modified it. and then it started working. still i can't explain what was actually the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has appeared due to a formatting issue of editing `nginx-ingress-controller` Kubernetes resource and was successfully fixed as well. However, even though for the common researches by the community contributors I would recommend to take a look at the general [Troubleshooting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/troubleshooting/) guideline for any related Kubernetes cluster issues and steps how to resolve them.